# Xamarin UWP - Listing Contacts does not work if compiled as Release

Tags: uwp, contacts, xamarin.uwp

I'm experiencing a very interesting UWP "bug".

I'm using Xamarin.Forms 2.3.3.193 and I need to list the contacts from the device.
In the UWP project everything works fine if it's compiled in Debug, but it doesn't work anymore if it's compiled in Release (of course Android and iOS are working fine always).

These are the 2 lines of code of the UWP service that lists the contacts:

```
        ContactStore store = await ContactManager.RequestStoreAsync(ContactStoreAccessType.AllContactsReadOnly);
        IReadOnlyList<Contact> contacts = await store.FindContactsAsync();
```

The *FindContactsAsync()* method returns the list when in debug but returns null when in release.

I also used the Xamarin.Plugin.Contacts from James Montemagno, but suffers the same fate.

Moreover, I tried the solution offered [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/94339/maps-do-not-work-in-uwp-app-compliled-with-release-configuration#latest) without any luck.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might occur when using the `Compile with .NET Native tool chain` which is an option for UWP apps in the **Properties > Build > General** window for the project.

Try to uncheck this option.

You tried to [do this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/94339/maps-do-not-work-in-uwp-app-compliled-with-release-configuration#latest) but it did not work for you. This should work according to [this article](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/platform-features/windows/installation/universal/#Troubleshooting).

Try changing your **App.xaml.cs** file in your **UWP project** follwing this:

```cs
// you'll need to add `using System.Reflection;`
List<Assembly> assembliesToInclude = new List<Assembly>();

//Now, add in all the assemblies your app uses
assembliesToInclude.Add(typeof (ContactManager).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);

Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(e, assembliesToInclude);
// replaces Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(e);
```

Comment: Thanks Wilson! That saved my day.

The compilation flag has remained checked, the culprit was the missing assembly. I got near but didn't try the right class (ContactManager).

Comment: You're welcome! I assume that's so I decided to put the correct code :)